# Why strtolower() does not follow the PHP strict Standard

Tags: php, strict

If i use

```
strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['file']['name'])));
```

it give me error

> > PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be passed by reference in

I thought ok I just  store the values in  a variables first, and then use explode

```
 $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
 $filearray = explode('.',$filename);
```

and it works fine

But i have another line

```
strtolower(end($filearray));
```

I thought it should give me the same error , i mean i should first have to store `end($filearray)` in a variable then use that variable in `strtolower()`,

But this is not giving me any error ,So why `strtolower()` accepting a function as parameter , and not giving an error , can someone explain why ?

Comment: BTW: completly offtopic, but raina77ow gave you allready a correct answer. But look to pathinfo for your case => pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"]). Gives you an Array with all you need (dirname, filename, extenstion and basename) http://php.net/manual/de/function.pathinfo.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not `strtolower` that gives you the warning - but `end` function. Quoting the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php):

> end() advances array's internal pointer to the last element, and
>   returns its value. [...] The array is passed by reference because it
>   is modified by the function. This means you must pass it a real
>   variable and not a function returning an array because only actual
>   variables may be passed by reference.

In your first example you attempt to `end` the result of `explode` call - i.e., not a real variable. While it's possible for PHP to ignore such a use case, it *usually* means that you've done something by mistake - and E_STRICT warning attempts to notify you about it.

Your third example works fine, because:

1) `strtolower` actually doesn't care about the reference. It *returns* a string with all alphabetic characters converted to lowercase instead of modifying the string in place.

2) `end` has a variable - array - passed in. It returns its last element, while advancing the internal pointer of that array to, well, its end. Have you attempted to employ this internal pointer (with `current` or some other means), you'd see the difference.

---

As a sidenote (already mentioned in comments by [@DoktorOSwaldo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5276188/doktor-oswaldo)), you can replace the all `explode(end()` stuff with simple [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) call:

```
$ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
```

Comment: But then `strtolower` is received function as reference. How come it's not throwing error? Can you elaborate more?

Comment: It didn't receive a _function_. It received the result of function call - the last element of `$filearray`. In the meantime, the internal pointer of `$filearray` has been moved to its last element.

Answer (score 1):

Because some functions in php are passed as a reference. **end** is one of those functions. see doc : http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php

But the **strtolower** function gets just a normal parameter.

So why does the **end** function gets a reference? **End** will not just return the last element, but will also move the array's internal pointer to the last element. so if you call **current** function after the **end** function you will get the last element. 
So basically end function will modify the array passed in parameter. And therefore it needs to be a variable that it can modify get as a reference.